# Chart JS is using 1,2,3 as y values for my points for the second dataset instead of their passed in labels

Tags: python, graph, charts, chart.js

I have two different datasets I'm trying to graph. One is a graph of about 50,000 values structured like [1.23, .53, 56.2, 53.6,...] and so on. That one prints fine and uses the correct labels. The labels for them are simply just 0 through the length of the list because it is sample numbers. For my second dataset, I want to put markers on the peak values. I have a function to find the peak values and am passing in that list as values2. Values2 looks like [56.765, 123.67, 46.241] for the peak value, left peak value and right peak value. And then the labels are their sample numbers, [12542, 67353, 32546]. Chart js just graphs those with the labels of 1,2,3 and sticks them directly along the y axis. I'm assuming that it's using the original labels values and assign values2[0] the label at labels[0] instead of labels2[0]. (I attached a screenshot of the graph). Thanks for any help. Below is my graphing html/JS code. I've looked at a lot of the other chart JS questions over the past 2 days and have consulted the chart JS website and documentation and nothing has been able to solve my problem. [image: 1]

```
  var line_chart = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: {{ labels | safe }},
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sweep data',
            data: {{ values | safe }},
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'Peak data',
            data: [{
              x: {{ values2 | safe }},
              y: {{ labels2 | safe }}
            }],
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1,
            showLine: true
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
      }
    }
    
    var context = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(context, line_chart);
```

---

I've tried splitting it into two datasets, highlighting the points, using 2 different context tags that will both be called on load of the window. The closest I got was splitting it into two separate datasets but then only the second portion was being graphed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant provide a seperate labels array in your dataset afaik, to achieve what you want you will have to provide the second dataset as an array containing objects where you can specify on which X coordinate you want the point to be

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: 1,
          y: 20
        }, {
          x: 3,
          y: 6
        }],
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        showLine: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: How would I do that when I don't know the values? I can't say what x and y equal until after I start the program, both are given programmatically for both datasets. I use a for loop in my main code to find the peak values and then put those peak values into a new peak_val_array which is passed as values2

Comment: I updated the code, are you saying something along those lines? It doesn't display any of the values from the second dataset now

Comment: you know the peak values and the index of that value so instead of pushing that value to your array you push an object to your array with key x and value index and key y and value is the value