# Show multiple line graphs on the same chart using chart JS

Tags: javascript, html, graph, chart.js

Right now I have two different datasets that are making two different graphs on the same page. I need one graph to be on top of the other one. This is what my JS/HTML looks like

```
<script>

        var data1 = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Sweep data',
                        data: {{ values | safe }},
                        backgroundColor: ['red'],
                        fill: false,
                        display: true               
                    }
                ],
                labels: {{ labels | safe }},
            }, 
            options: {
            }
        };

        var data2 = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Peak data',
                        data: {{ values2 | safe }},
                        backgroundColor: ['black'],
                        fill: false,
                        display: true               
                    }
                ],
                labels: {{ labels2 | safe }},
            }, 
            options: {
            }
        };


        
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, data1);  

    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2, data2);  
};
```

I know that it's making multiple graphs because I have two ctx variables, what I don't know is how to only call the new Chart function once, but pass it both data sets. The datasets do not have the same amount of labels, but the second graph is the peak points of the first graph, so those are included in the original set of labels.

I've tried working around this and highlighting the peak points instead but did not get anywhere with that. Both sets of labels and data points are passed in correctly. I can console them both to see the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's needed

```
            data: [{
            x: {{ labels2[0] | safe }},
            y: {{ values2[0] | safe }}
            }, {
            x: {{ labels2[1] | safe }},
            y: {{ values2[1] | safe }}
            }, {
            x: {{ labels2[2] | safe }},
            y: {{ values2[2] | safe }}
            }, {
            x: {{ labels2[3] | safe }},
            y: {{ values2[3] | safe }}
            }]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple line charts on the same graph you will need to put the dataset objects in the datasets array instead of making the chart twice like so:

```
datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Sweep data',
                        data: {{ values | safe }},
                        backgroundColor: ['red'],
                        fill: false,
                        display: true               
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Peak data',
                        data: {{ values2 | safe }},
                        backgroundColor: ['black'],
                        fill: false,
                        display: true               
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: That graphs the second line graph (values2) with the same labels as values1. Meaning that each point in values2 uses labels [1,2,3,4] instead of their actual labels.

Comment: Well see my answer on your same question for how to fix that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520696/chart-js-is-using-1-2-3-as-y-values-for-my-points-for-the-second-dataset-instead

Comment: Read my comments under that same question explaining how that did not help me or solve my problem, leading me to ask the question again.

Comment: yeah well instead of asking your question multiple times which wont help either read better because you did it wrong and not as I explained